# Function isChanged() for many variables

Tags: c++, macros

Given a variable `var_1`, I want:

```
if(isChanged(var_1))
{
  Alert("The value of the variable just changed compared to last time");
}
```

...but the same `bool isChanged(){/* function body*/}` needs to work for ***any number of variables***, for ***any data type*** and ***without interfering*** with each other.

I think this is not possible out of the box in C++, but maybe someone very well versed e.g. in macros, macro constants and the macro-paste-token `##` can create the `static [data type]` `var_last_1`, `var_last_2`, `var_last_3` etc. needed for the comparison with the respective `var_1`, `var_2`, `var_3`'s etc. last values *dynamically* through a hack?

Comment: That's usually a case to use a container parameter like `std::vector<data type>` as parameter.

Comment: When is the "last time"? Is something changed if it has never been seen before?

Comment: it is not even obvious what you actually want for a single variable. If you have a `/*function body*/` which works for `var_1` as you desire you should show it. If not, do that first. Once you can tell us what you want for a single variable we can tell you how to do the same for any number and any type

Comment: Protect the variable with setter?

Comment: It's easily done in out-of-the-box C++.  Just program the variable that way, with a template for any type.

Comment: What is your current implementation of `isChanged`?

Comment: Do you require this to be used in a multithreaded environment? And what constitutes a change? That is has been written to since last read? And for floating points how precise? And do you actively want to poll? Or do you want callback function(s) to be called. You need to be clear on all those things before it is possible to really answer your question.

Comment: Seems like a classic case of trying very hard to solve the wrong problem. You don't say why you want the feature, but that's where you should really be looking for a solution. You also asked this before I think?

Comment: This is a classic [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Are you trying to implement the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in C++?

Comment: @Eljay ...except for the case that the variable name should literally appear in the output string. In this case, the stringize operator of the preprocessor is in fact the only tool at hand, isn't it? (I'm not aware of what becomes available with the reflection features of C++20+.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat • for that situation I use `#define NAMEOF(x) #x`.  Inspired by **C#**.

Answer (score 1):

Variables do not keep track of their modifications unless you write the code to do so. Think about it: You need more than the variable itself. You need either the current value and the past value or some `bool` flag that you need to manage accordingly.

It seems like you are trying to solve a problem at the wrong end, but you didnt tell us about that underlying problem. Anyhow, maybe you are looking for encapsulation:

```
struct my_changing_int {
private:
    int value = 42;
    bool has_changed = false;
public:
    void set(int x) { has_changed = (x != value); value = x; }
    bool isChanged() { 
         bool temp = has_changed;
         has_changed = false;
         return temp;
    }
};
```

If you want this for other types than `int` you can make it a template.

Comment: _error C2365: 'my_changing_int::has_changed': redefinition; previous definition was 'data member'_

Comment: Possibly: `bool isChanged() { return std::exchange(has_changed, false); }` [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange).